# Added new DC now OS X cannot access network accounts

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, mac-osx

I have 2 iMacs on our network that use AD to authenticate.  It has been working fine for quick a while.  The domain controller has been Windows Server 2003, which I am in the process of replacing.  I added a new Windows Server 2012 machine last week, and elevated it to a domain controller.  As part of the process of making the new machine a DC, I had to upgrade the Active directory from 2000 to 2003 (I think).  All the PCs and 1 iMac are working fine.  However, the iMac running OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan) is saying network accounts are unavailable.  I can still access the network shares from the iMac, though.  The older iMac (still running Lion I think) still recognizes the network accounts without any problems.  Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: It turns out my problem was that I inadvertently deleted the machine from the AD.  I backed up the user's files in single user mode, then unbound the computer and rebound it to the domain.  Fortunately, the user's profile and files remained intact, and the backup was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The AD protocol or encryption methods may have changed significantly from Windows Server 2003 to 2012.

There's a [walkthrough](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/integrate-macs-into-a-windows-active-directory-domain/) on techrepublic that says it's for 10.5 - 10.9 and Windows 2012 - go through that and see if you're missing anything on the OS X clients.